# Definite Integral Evaluation

Tags: definite-integrals

Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2}x^3\sqrt{(2x-x^2)} dx$

This kind of problem is solved using tricks like putting $\displaystyle x=\sin^2t$ and/or  identities like

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{a}f(x) dx &=\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x) dx
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2a}f(x) dx & = \int_{0}^{a}f(2a-x) dx,\; if \; f(2a-x)=f(x) \\ 
 & = 0,\qquad \qquad \qquad if \; f(2a-x)=-f(x) \\ 
\end{align}$$

I am not able to find a relevant replacement here. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2}x^3 \sqrt{2x-x^2} dx=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2}x^3\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2} dx$$
Now setting $$x-1=\sin t$$ we obtain
$$I=\displaystyle \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin t+1)^3 \cos^2 t dt$$

Answer (score 2):

Why doesn't $x = \sin^2 t$ work? Try to answer that first.
*Hint: Look at the limits*

Once you've figured out why that doesn't work, you should be able to guess what modification you need to do to that substitution to make it work.
*Hint: How will you make the limits match the range?*

It might help if you rewrite the integral as:
$$\int_0^2 x^{7/2}\sqrt{2-x}\,dx$$

If it were $1 - x$, then $x = \sin^2 t$ would've worked, as you would get $1 - \sin^2 t = \cos^2 t$. Here though, it's $2 - x$, and $2 - \sin^2 t = 1 + \cos^2 t$, which doesn't help. How will you get rid of that extra $1$? Can you make that $\cos^2 t$ as well?